# Entity Framework: Invalid column name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have problem with this `Conference` table. The error is :

> Invalid column name 'Conference_ConferenceID'

[image]

```
namespace MeetingBoard.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    using MeetingBoard.Model.Helpers;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    /// <summary>
    /// A model of the Conference entity. Contains functionality to serialize the entity to JSON as well.
    /// </summary>
    public class Conference
    {
        [Key]
        public int ConferenceID { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int CreatorID { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }
        public DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("CreatorID")]
        public virtual User Creator { get; set; }

        public int[] RelatedProjectsIDs { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProjectTag> RelatedProjectTags { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn
        {
            get { return (this.dateCreated == default(DateTime)) ? DateTime.UtcNow : this.dateCreated; }
            set { this.dateCreated = value; }
        }
        private DateTime dateCreated = default(DateTime);

        public virtual ICollection<Group> RelatedGroups { get; set; }

        public Conference()
        {
            RelatedGroups = new List<Group>();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Generates an object that can be serialized by the JSON serializer of MVC
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="happening">An Conference.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Object ToJsonObject(Conference conference)
        {
            int[] project_ids = conference.RelatedProjectTags.Select<ProjectTag, int>(pt => pt.ProjectID).ToArray();



            return new Conference_JSON
            {
                id = conference.ConferenceID,
                title = conference.Title,
                Content = conference.Content,
                created_timestamp_UTC = Util.DateTimeToMilliTimeStamp(conference.CreatedOn),
                SubmissionDate = conference.SubmissionDate,
                Location = conference.Location,

                creator_avatar = conference.Creator.Avatar,
                creator_fullname = conference.Creator.Name,
                creator_id = conference.Creator.UserID,

                project_ids = project_ids,

            };
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Instantiates a new Conference object based on the json data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="json_data">The json data needs to have the structure as specified in the private Conference_JSON object.</param>
        /// <returns>A new Conference object. The related projects are referenced using an integer array containing project ids.</returns>
        public static Conference FromJson(String json_data)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Conference_JSON conference_object = serializer.Deserialize<Conference_JSON>(json_data);

            return FromJsonObject(conference_object);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Instantiates a new Conference object based on the private Conference_JSON object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="json_data">The object needs to be an instance of the private Conference_JSON object.</param>
        /// <returns>A new Conference object. The related projects are referenced using an integer array containing project ids.</returns>
        public static Conference FromJsonObject(Object conference_object)
        {
            Conference_JSON conference_json = (Conference_JSON)conference_object;

            Conference conference = new Conference
            {
                ConferenceID = conference_json.id,
                Title = conference_json.title,
                Content = conference_json.Content,
                RelatedProjectsIDs = conference_json.project_ids,
                Location = conference_json.Location,
                SubmissionDate = conference_json.SubmissionDate,

            };
            return conference;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the structure of the json objects that ar communicated to and from the Frontend.
        /// </summary>
        private class Conference_JSON
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The Conference identifier.
            /// </summary>
            public int id;
            public string title;
            public string Content;

            /// <summary>
            /// An numeric representation of the time, in milliseconds from Unix Epoch, UTC timezone.
            /// </summary>
            public double created_timestamp_UTC;

            public string creator_fullname;
            public int creator_id;
            public string creator_avatar;

            /// <summary>
            /// Related projects.
            /// </summary>
            public int[] project_ids;
            public string Location;
            public DateTime SubmissionDate;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: code first or DB first.   Where is the error thrown? SSMS or VS ?

Comment: Generally such error comes if there are not found matching column in database. I suggest you check column name in corresponding table.

Comment: Is this a compile- or runtime error?

Comment: Why is there a one-to-one relationship between `ProjectTag` and `Conference` in your database schema? In your model `RelatedProjectTags` is a collection which indicates a one-to-many relationship. Could you show the `ProjectTag` entity class? And perhaps mapping with Fluent API if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when there is a mismatch between the code and the DB, in the sense that the code expects to find columns in the DB but they don't exist there. This happens when the DB isn't updated to match the changes in the code. I'd suggest looking at the database that is being hit when you get that error, maybe it's not looking where you expect.